# Dynamic page numbering using XSL snippet

Tags: xslt

I have page numbers in sequential order within a RTF document. However my document output has multiple documents in sequential order. My first document is of 4 pages, the second is for 3 pages and 3rd 2 pages. My single document output throws out a RTF document comprising of all three documents. But the page no.s are in increasing order 1,2,3,4 ....
Ideally I would want my second document to start from page 1 and so is the case with my third document.
How do I accomplish this using XSL coding within the footer ?

Thanks.

Comment: An example input XML would be nice

Answer (score 0):

In XSL-FO to restart page numbers in a page sequence use `initial-page-number="1"` on your `<fo:page-sequence>` element.

Whether that works for your RTF output or not is up to the vendor of your software.  What I've given you is what the specification says to do.